# Smooth side menu animation with icons

Tags: html, css

I want to animate when my side menu expands and collapses but the way it is structured stops me from using transform (or at least I'm not sure how to properly use it). I am currently using width to animate it and it isn't too smooth, especially with my relative div on the right which contains a grid that slows down the animation even more (it's not as visible on pages where I don't have any grids or tables).

Because my icons are on the left I can't use `translateX` to animate it because the icons wouldn't be initially visible.

I've tried using `scale` but the menu was just 'squeezed' when it collapsed and expanded.

What approach shall I be using really to make a smooth animation and not be limited by heavily re-scaled relative div. I know it's smooth but once I'd start adding some heavy content on the relative right div, animating using width is just painful to watch.

[image]

Here's an example

```js
const sideMenu = document.getElementById('sidemenu');

sideMenu.addEventListener('click', function() {
 sideMenu.classList.toggle('collapsed');
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  display: flex;
}

#sidemenu {
  width: 170px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #EB7575;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#sidemenu.collapsed {
  width: 60px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}

ul li a {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li a span {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
}

.icon {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.relative-div {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.10-1/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  
  <body>
    <div id="sidemenu">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <i class="icon ion-md-settings"></i><span>Settings</span>
          </a>
          <a href="#">
            <i class="icon ion-md-add"></i><span>Add something</span>
          </a>
          <a href="#">
            <i class="icon ion-md-download"></i><span>Download bits</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div class="relative-div">
      Relative div
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just animate width while having overflow...

Comment: @Akxe that's what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options (to my knowledge):

- Make the nav position fixed/absolute, while adding padding to the body, to prevent relative div to go beneath it. **Downside:** The nav will be above content once extended.
- Move both, nav & div, to prevent the recalculation of layers. **Downside:** Content will be off the screen.
- Don't worry till you actually notice it is a problem.